# Drawing a 3d textured rectangle - no texture

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I am trying to draw a textured rectangle like in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464051.aspx) msdn example, but I only get a black rectangle without a texture.

The output:
[image]

My draw method:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

    effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
    effect.World = Matrix.Identity;
    effect.Projection = camera.Projection;
    effect.View = camera.View;
    effect.TextureEnabled = true;
    effect.Texture = grass;

    foreach (var pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
    {
        pass.Apply();

        GraphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, quad.Vertices, 0, 4, AlignedQuad.Indexes, 0, 2);
    }

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

`effect` is like in the msdn example a `BasicEffect`. `grass` is loaded correctly and is not a black texture.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: download the zip on the msdn page. It might help you

Comment: I think you made a mistakes with your normal vecotr2. This causes no light -> black color.

Comment: @RobinDijkhof What do you mean exactly?